# Clean up sensor data from Gym environment

Tags: python, multithreading, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have a Reinforcement learning program that uses the OpenAI gym module to create an environment. I get data from a sensor and the RL problem is based on the sensor data, the RL problem is not the main focus of this question, I want to save all the sensor data after the program is finished, according to the OpenAI Gym documentation `Environments will automatically close() themselves when garbage collected or when the program exits.`. So I thought I could just write all my data to a file in this function, but it is never called.

this is the code for my environment, still a work in progress but that is not the focus of this question

```py
class StressEnvironment(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, images) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.images = images
        self.sensor = Sensor()
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=np.array([0], dtype=np.float32),high=np.array([100],dtype=np.float32),shape=(1,))
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.sensor.main)
        self.thread.start()

    def step(self, action):
        #TODO execute action
        new_state = np.array([self.sensor.breathing_rate])
        reward = -self.sensor.breathing_rate
        return new_state,reward,False, {}
    
    def reset(self):
        return np.array([self.sensor.breathing_rate])
    
    def close(self):
        # save sensor data to file
        print("saving sensor data to file")
        print(len(self.sensor.data))
```

this is my main.py

```py
from environment import StressEnvironment

env = StressEnvironment([])
```

I also cannot kill my terminal with Ctrl+C, this is caused by the thread which has an infinite loop (just collecting sensor data all the time).

So my question is why isn't close() called and is the way I use this thread good or not ?

Answer (score -3):

It seems like the issue you're facing is related to the close() method of your StressEnvironment class not being called automatically. The close() method in OpenAI Gym environments is typically used to clean up resources and perform any necessary actions before the environment is closed. In your case, you want to save sensor data to a file when the environment is closed.

To address this issue, you can explicitly call the close() method on your environment when you're done using it. Here's how you can modify your main.py to ensure that the close() method is called:

```
from environment import StressEnvironment

env = StressEnvironment([])

# Your RL program here

# When you're done using the environment, call close
env.close()
```

By explicitly calling env.close(), you ensure that the close() method is executed, and you can save your sensor data to a file within the close() method as you've already implemented.

Regarding your use of the thread, it seems reasonable for collecting sensor data asynchronously. However, keep in mind that if you want to gracefully exit the program with Ctrl+C, you should add a mechanism to stop the thread when you receive a termination signal. You can use a flag or an event to signal the thread to stop gracefully when the program exits. This way, you can avoid having to forcefully terminate the program.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to handle Ctrl+C and stop the thread gracefully:

```
import signal

# Define a flag to signal the thread to stop
stop_thread = False

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    global stop_thread
    stop_thread = True

# Set up a signal handler for Ctrl+C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

from environment import StressEnvironment

env = StressEnvironment([])

# Your RL program here

# When you're done or when Ctrl+C is pressed, stop the thread and close the environment
stop_thread = True  # Signal the thread to stop
env.close()  # Close the environment
```

This modification allows you to handle Ctrl+C gracefully by stopping the thread and closing the environment before exiting the program.

Comment: This reads like a ChatGPT answer. Please consider making your own answer that is less verbose and ensure that it actually works.

Comment: @AlexM Good call, but sadly the "user" probably has no interest in improving the answer (or even returning to the site).  Note the profile pic, bio text, and link -- This is a SEO profile spammer.  They even sought out a question on Gym sensor data to (presumably) optimize the search results.